# iPhone custom browser app programmatically create 'Bookmark' on Home Screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

We are trying to create a custom browser app for iPhone. In this app we would like to be able to allow the user to click on a link labeled "Add to Homescreen" just like Safari browser does and have our custom browser add the link/icon to the homescreen (just a web app link/url).
Is this possible and if so where do we look to figure out how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

please check "App Store Review Guidelines.

it says

10.4 Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-app widget experiences will be rejected,

thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with adding a bookmark on the home screen?!

Comment: it is pretty much clear, question was can we add bookmark/link icon to spring board and guidelines says you can't. one app one icon you can't create bookmark or any other icons.